# Safe and polymorphic Enum in Haskell

Tags: haskell, enums, polymorphism

I'm trying to write total versions of the unsafe `Enum` functions:

```
predMay :: Enum a => a -> Maybe a
succMay :: Enum a => a -> Maybe a
toEnumMay :: Enum a => Int -> Maybe a
```

My problem is that the unsafe functions are only partial if the `Enum` is also `Bounded`, so safe versions should have a different form in the two cases:

```
predMayUnboundedEnum :: Enum a => a -> Maybe a
predMayUnboundedEnum = Just . pred

predMayBoundedEnum :: (Enum a, Bounded a) => a -> Maybe a
predMayBoundedEnum x
  | fromEnum x == fromEnum (minBound `asTypeOf` x) = Nothing
  | otherwise  = Just (pred x)
```

The best idea I've had to get the function I want is to use another typeclass:

```
class Enum a => SafeEnum a where
  predMay :: a -> Maybe a
instance Enum a => SafeEnum a where
  predMay = predMayUnboundedEnum
instance (Enum a, Bounded a) => SafeEnum a where
  predMay = predMayBoundedEnum
```

but this causes a complaint about `Duplicate instance declarations`.

Do I have the right idea here, or is there a better way to approach this problem?  Has someone else already done this?  (I'm aware of the package [prelude-safeenum](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/prelude-safeenum), but the primary advantage of `Enum` for me is that we can `deriving` it.) Are these safe functions even possible, or are `Enum`s in the wild too hairy to let such a simple solution be safe?

Comment: I suggest you do write your own class, and use `DefaultSignatures` to 'derive' it automatically (i.e. you will write `instance SafeEnum X` for a suitable `X`), and with `DeriveAnyClass` in ghc8 you would even be able to write `data X where ... deriving (SafeEnum)`, which would be equivalent to the above instance. Your problem is you want to *decide* if a type has an instance, which is simply impossible - it violates the semantics of classes. Also, Enum is generally considered completely lawless so you may find your assumptions about Enum/Bounded do not always holds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This cannot be done. Remember that Haskell type classes are *open*. Your proposal requires to do something different depending on whether or not a type belongs to the `Bounded` class. But you can never know a type *doesn't* belong to this class. (Well, *you* can know that e.g. `Integer` must not have a `Bounded` instance, but *the compiler* can not. Nothing stops you from defining a nonsense `instance Bounded Integer where {minBound = 7; maxBound = 3}` except common sense.)

The only reliable way to get the correct instances is to sort types manually in bounded-or-not. This can be done consisely enough, especially with a default:

```
class Enum a => SafeEnum a where
  predMay :: a -> Maybe a
  predMay = predMayUnboundedEnum

instance SafeEnum Integer
instance SafeEnum Rational
instance SafeEnum Int where predMay = predMayBoundedEnum
...
```